# Play Framework form example in Java

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I start to learn Play Framework 2.5 version, search a lot in the web but cant find a good form basic input example. Can someone give me a functional example of a form input using Java?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can search any things for programming in GOOGLE but here is just for SO, not for learning a programming language!

Comment: Two places I'd look would be: [the Java Forms page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaForms) in the docs, and then at some actual code in one of the templates, such as [the computer database](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/computer-database-java) template.

Comment: wwkudu is actually right. I would also recommend the official Play documentation as a good starting point. Try it and if you have a specific question, don't hesitate to ask. The correct link for 2.5 is https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [Media Naranja](http://medianaranja.herokuapp.com/), you can find the complete project over [here](https://github.com/yovasx2/media-naranja)

It includes:

- Forms
- Database connection
- Websockets
- Models
- Controllers
- Views in Scala